# basic jQuery click handler doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, click, handler

I've got a weird problem with click handlers in jQuery. I wrote a userscript and it works fine in Firefox. (Greasemonkey addon)
At first I thought it ran fine in chrome too(because the script loads fine and I don't get any errors in the console) but as it turns out none of my buttons are working. I'm using Tampermonkey addon for chrome.

Here is the code I'm using for handlers:

```
  $(function(){
      function count_send_at(event) {
          //...
          return false;
      }
      $('#count_send_at_btn').click(count_send_at);
  });
```

`count_send_at()` doesn't get called at all (tested with an alert).

I couldn't find any solution on the Internet, maybe you can help me.

Comment: I think I found it; I tried it and got similar behavior. For me, the script didn't have access to the jQuery object, which is what I kind of suspect is happening to you. Take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/EpnXh/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     function count_send_at(event) {
     //...
        return false;
     }
     $('#count_send_at_btn').click(count_send_at);
});
```

Comment: this raises an exception:
ERROR: Execution of script 'xxx' failed! object is not a function
TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: What exception does it raise? Is it raising "object is not a function?" And are you running Strict mode?

Comment: Yes that's the exception is gives. I do not use strict mode as far as I know. There's no "use strict" anywhere in my script.

Comment: Did you remove the leading $?  (function() { instead of $(function() {

Comment: I removed the $ but it still doesn't call my function. The exception doesn't happen anymore though

Comment: Doesn't matter if I add document ready around the "function(){..." nor if I add it around "$('#count_send_at_btn').click(count_send_at);".

Comment: Sounds like jQuery might not be in the dom, or he $ symbol is conflicting. Can you show us the code you're using to include jQuery onto your page?

Comment: The page isn't mine, I only developed a script that uses a preloaded jQuery. It happens to be version 1.7.1 minimal. Should I try loading a second(newer) version just for my script? Such basic thing like a button handler should work fine even in old versions in my opinion

Answer (score -1):

I tried something similar and got the same behavior; it was complaining that '$' was undefined, which means the user script doesn't have access to the jQuery object.

Here's an approach to fix it:

```
function GM_wait() {
    // if chrome, of course. this might need to be handled differently in firefox...
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
        window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
    } else { 
        $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; 
    }
}

(function(){
    GM_wait();

    if ( $ ) {
        alert('got it!');
    }
})();
```

Cortesy of: http://forum.imerx.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=127

Comment: I am pretty sure it doesn't conflict with any other framework as the script works just fine in Firefox. Your way of doing it doesn't work for me unfortunately but just now I noticed that the script breaks in jQuery code 3 times during page load. it's the 2nd line of jQuery v1.7.1 minimal. After disabling my script it breaks there only once.

Comment: I already have a function like that in my code. $ is defined.
I've been trying to make it work by making the function the way you showed earlier:
"unsafeWindow.count_send_at = function(event)"
By doing that I can run it from console, but I cannot seem to attach it to a button. This code:
$('#count_send_at_btn').attr("onClick", "count_send_at()")
works(aka attaches the handler) when running it from console, but no combination that I could think of works from the script.

Comment: Ah, sorry! You didn't mention that in your original question.

Comment: Try one last thing; change $("#count_send_at_btn").click(..); to: $(unsafeWindow.document).find("#count_send_at_btn").click(...); and see if that works.

Comment: It does not, unfortunately. It works from console(after deleting the unsafeWindow part). About the breaks in code execution - I didn't see them earlier because I didn't have the filter set to "pause on all exceptions" before. They are all "caught" so I don't think the problem lies there. Also, if you want, I can send you(privately please) the full script + webpage address for you to fiddle with. It's currently 2:20 AM here, so I will be going to bed soon.

Comment: Sure, I'm really curious now :)